# Incomplete answers with chain rule and directional derivatives

Tags: multivariable-calculus

In this question asking to use the chaing rule to compute dz/dx & dz/dy, I always seem to get a missing 1/2. Where does it come from?
$$
2x^2+3y^2-2z^2 = 9
$$

I start with separating z.

$$
2z^2 = 2x^2
$$
$$
z^2 = x^2
$$
$$
z = x^2/z
$$
Then,
$$
dz/dx = 2x/z
$$

The actual answer is x/z. I keep getting this for the two examples and for all cases. Similar but off by a constant.

---

As for the directional derivative question, I don't think I have the right formula as I don't even know where the 30 degrees goes in this question:

Find 
$$
D_uf  for  f = e^x cos(y)
$$
in the direction 30 degrees from the positive x-axies at the point (1, pi/4).

The formula I have is
$$
D_uf =   \bigtriangledown f(a,b)   \bullet  \langle u  \rangle 
$$

EDIT: To be more specific for my second issue, I meant to say how do I bring in the 30 degrees to the formula in order to solve the problem? The final answer is 
$$
e  \surd(2)(\surd(3)-1)/4
$$

Those are square roots, \sqrt didn't seem to work.

---

These are the last questions I'm stuck with for my test tomorrow, so any and all help is appreciated

Comment: The first step you tried is wrong, you cant separate x from y from z, its just not possible. If however you just take the derivative with rspect to x the y term disappears because y isnt a function of x

Comment: Yeah I saw trying to find Fx so 9 and 3y^2 can be removed since they're constants.

Comment: Only as far as differentiation wrt x is concerned yes, and thd chain rule is needed for the z term